# How best to over come 2 different DB system designs using OOP?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, code-reuse

I need to write some middle ware code to move data between two third party student systems. These systems both have their own completely different Web Service API. 
My plan is to build custom wrapper on the top of each Web Service API and then build a Common assembly over the top of both Wrappers to move data between the systems and allow for further development on a common code base.  There is about 12 other applications using these systems directly and maintenance is becoming unmanageable. I want to build something that they can be migrated to.

In pseudo-code

```
//System one out puts
Class Student_SytemA {
Public StudentID {get;set;} //PKID System A
Public FName {get;set;}
Public LName {get;set;}
Public DOB {get;set;}
}

//System two out puts

Class Student_SystemB{
Public ContactID {get;set;} //PK SystemB
Public FirstName {get;set;}
Public LastName {get;set;}
Public DateOfBirth {get;set;}
Public StudentID_REF {get;set;} //Reference to System A
}
```

This sort of thing is endemic through out both systems where they are holding the exact same information just under different field names or data structures.

My thought is to have something like this

```
Class Student_Comman{
Public ContactID {get;set;}  
Public FirstName {get;set;}
Public LastName {get;set;}
Public DateOfBirth {get;set;}
Public StudentID_REF {get;set;} 

Public WireUpSystemA(Student_SystemA student){
StudentID_REF  = student .StudentID;
FirstName  = student .FName ;
LastName = student .LName ;
DateOfBirth = student .DOB ;
}

Public WireUpSystemB(Student_SystemB student){
StudentID_REF  = student . StudentID_REF  ;
FirstName  = student . FirstName  ;
LastName = student . LastName;
DateOfBirth = student . DateOfBirth;
}

}
```

How do I go about bringing these together architecturally using OOP so that I am writing and maintaining the least amount of wiring up code? 
I would like to use inheritance if I can to cut down coding and maintenance? 
Is there a better way of going about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For cases like yours, I prefer a reflection/generic approach.

Mark the properties of A and B with an attribute which tells to which property must be mapped in your target type and create just one generic converter:

```
//Custom attribute class
sealed class RedirectedPropertyAttribute : Attribute
{
    readonly string targetProperty;

    public RedirectedPropertyAttribute(string TargetProperty)
    {
        this.targetProperty = TargetProperty;
    }

    public string TargetProperty
    {
        get { return targetProperty; }
    }
}

//Type converter
public class TypeConverter
{

    public static T Convert<T, S>(S Source) where T : class, new() where S : class, new()
    {
        //If no instance is passed just return null
        if (Source == null)
            return null;


        //Get types of items
        Type typeOfTarget = typeof(T);
        Type typeOfSource = typeof(S);

        //Get properties of items
        var sourceProperties = typeOfSource.GetProperties();
        var targetProperties = typeOfTarget.GetProperties();

        //Create a new instance of T
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();

        foreach (var prop in sourceProperties)
        {
            //Get or attributes
            var attribs = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(RedirectedPropertyAttribute), false); //If you want to inherit the attributes change to yes

            //If it's not marked or marked more than once, continue (really a bad error ;))
            if (attribs == null || attribs.Length != 1)
                continue;

            //Cast the attribute
            RedirectedPropertyAttribute attrib = attribs[0] as RedirectedPropertyAttribute;

            //No property set? ignore this property
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(attrib.TargetProperty))
                continue;

            //Find the target property in target type
            var tProp = targetProperties.Where(t => t.Name == attrib.TargetProperty).FirstOrDefault();

            //Not found? ignore this property
            if (tProp == null)
                continue;

            try
            {

                //Why this try-catch?
                //Because if types don't match an exception can be thrown
                //but it's easier than comparing types (because if an int is mapped to a long we want it to be set)

                //WARNING!!, assuming non-indexed properties!
                tProp.SetValue(instance, prop.GetValue(Source, null), null);
            }
            catch { }
        }

        //Return new class
        return instance;

    }

}

//Class from source A
public class A
{
    [RedirectedProperty("Id")]
    public int IdOfA { get; set; }

    [RedirectedProperty("Name")]
    public string StringOfA { get; set; }

}

//Class from source B
public class B
{
    [RedirectedProperty("Id")]
    public int IdOfB { get; set; }

    [RedirectedProperty("Name")]
    public string StringOfB { get; set; }

}

//Hub class for A or B
public class ABHub
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

}

//And to use:
ABHub ACasted = TypeConverter.Convert<ABHub, A>(new A{ IdOfA = 33, StringOfA = "MyNameIsA" });
ABHub BCasted = TypeConverter.Convert<ABHub, B>(new B{ IdOfB = 33, StringOfB = "MyNameIsB" });
```

Comment: I like this idea. I thought of trying this myself for wiring up the objects but I was not shore exactly how but Custom Attributes is a great idea. One problem though, the one system uses Bool and the other uses T/F strings. I see you have a Try Catch to get around different data type issues. Perhaps I could add a TargetType to the RedirectedPropertyAttribute and check for that to define if a conversion/transformation is needed.

Comment: Yes, you can explicitly set it in your attribute adding another parameter, or you just can check types of source property and target property and cast with your own function. If the only problem is when target is boolean and source is string you can do a bool.Parse(sourceProperty).

Comment: The problem would be more knowing which strings need to be transformed and that can be indicated by the attribute. I will still be maintaining three classes of code for every Entity, one for System A, one for System B and the Hub/proxy for the common assembly, I am starting to think that this is going to be inevitable. Is there any way to get around this with inheritance and a Base student class?

Comment: You are using a webservice, no? if so, those classes will be auto generated by vs, so you only need to maintain the hub ones. Also, to the first part, if the target is a boolean you know already it must be converted if you tagged the right target property.

Comment: I think I am going to have to code the Wrappers my self. I am trying to make sure that if the systems are upgraded or change for new ones there is the smallest amount of changes possible. So I was hoping to create common objects that can be inherited from and used by both wrappers. In less there is a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Moving data between two 3rd party systems can be thorny to maintain especially if they potentially change the properties/methods they expose.

Is the scope of your project just to move data back and forth between the two systems? If-so, take a look at SSIS packages.

Here are some benefits of SSIS:

- SSIS packages core use case is to move data from one place to another. This is also called ETL (Extract Transform Load).
- Visual display of the columns and what they are mapped to
- Custom modules can be created in SSIS that are written in C#
- SSIS packages learning curve is really low. They're easy to create.

Here are some downsides of SSIS:

- No native support for RESTful service. However this article seems to have a good solution: https://markarlenplace.wordpress.com/2010/12/30/consuming-restful-web-services-in-an-ssis-script-transformation/
- Error Handling - Basic error handling is fine but I was moving large chunks of data around from one database table to another. If there was an exception from the data, I needed to know the table/row/column that it occurred at. It took a while to implement a solution for this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would also add they are incredibly time consuming to troubleshoot and they don’t cope will with changes to underlying systems meta data.  Unfortunately as mentioned in my question, I will want to be migrating all the custom applications that work with these two systems onto using the same base code.  So SSIS is not something that I am wanting to use for this project.

Comment: Good point, SSIS isn't a good solution for you. I don't recommend using Reflection. It's really slow to use and also brittle. Have you considered using dynamic types like ExpandoObject?

Comment: I am aware of the reflection speed issue. When I have used reflection in the past I have created a Static object variable that stored the field mappings in a list and checked there first and if they were not in the list then done the reflection and stored them in the list for the next time round. It helps a bit with performance. Thanks for the advice.